# How can i change the size of this cone? Can I make a lattice to the exact shape of my object?

Tags: modifiers, lattice

[image]

I have this cone with the sizes of 70x40x140mm and I want to turn it into 60x40x140mm, without ruining the decoration on them. I tried a few things and up until now, lattices seem to be the best idea. Can I make a lattice to the exact size and shape of the cone? If not I'm open to any suggestions. Please help.

Comment: so it looks like you've tried with a lattice, what does it give and what problem are you meeting?

Comment: Maybe missing the point, but a new cone like this one can be made in 5 or 6 moves?

Comment: If you want a linear interpolation for the objects under the influence of the lattice, you need to change the interpolation mode in the lattice data properties

Comment: The trouble is, with _any_  linear scale the knurling would get shallower, proportionately?

Comment: @moonboots so, I tried to make the top face larger, but I can not control with mm precision how large to make it, I need it to be an exact size. I tried to use measureit while enlarging the face but the segment measurement won't "grow" together with the object. I'm a beginner, maybe I can not use the modifiers correctly yet, I'm open to any suggestuins

Comment: @Robin Betts You are not missing the point at all, I was looking for a faster option. I'm a beginner so I don't know that much about blender.

Comment: @Gorgious I see, I speak 3 languages, but not this one. I will look into this, I have a lot to learn, thank you.

Comment: @ Robin Betts well, I have not observed this on my object, but I will follow your first comment and redo the cone in the size I need it. Thank you